# USB light sensor (ALS) product or implementation?

Tags: arduino, usb, firmware

I've been looking for a way to retrofit light sensors to my laptops which lack one.

The best specification I've found so far is in the ACPI 3b spec, section 9.2, that details how such a sensor would be implemented. I assume Linux would also follow the spec.

My first question: is there such a device on the market? A small USB dongle that measures light and provides that to the OS. I already have a Spyder i1 that can do this, but it's overkill and large.

Second question: would it be possible to implement this using Arduino and V-USB? If yes, how would one approach the project?

Is it even possible to do this via USB?

Background: a small USB microcontroller and an LED can function decently as a light sensor by measuring LED capacitance, with no other external parts. This is well documented and also tested by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have a microcontroller with a USB stack already you can use a *photoresistor, photodiode* and convert the *voltage, resistance,current* to a digital signal with the ADC of the uC, see http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_4.html there are also ICs available (search for '*ambient light sensor ic*') if you don not wnat ot use the ADC there are ICs that can be connected to I2C bus etc

normally sensors are implement **USB HID class**, see http://www.sensorwiki.org/doku.php/tutorials/building_a_usb_sensor_interface

the linux kernel module (driver) for ambient light sensors is `acpi-als.ko` or in case of a usb (HID) light sensor `hid-sensor-als.ko`

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/iio/light/hid-sensor-als.c

( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/hid/hid-sensor.txt, https://lwn/net/Articles/348576/ )
if you build an own device you have to make it compliant to this driver

there are ready solutions for this (http://www.hughski.com/colorhugals , http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-environmental-sensors/yocto-light-v3 ) but they are really expensive

the windows driver is *sensor-hid-class-driver* ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/sensor-hid-class-driver).

(https://www.chalk-elec.com/?p=2144 control LCD backlight over HID USB)

Comment: The ColorHug hint is the most useful as the blog post points to a readable firmware code that does exactly that. Also found something a bit closer to my intended implementation: https://github.com/edy555/avr-hidtemp and http://vusb.wikidot.com/project:hid-sensor-example-compatible-with-windows8-8-1-10-b